# Rendering multiple overlapping non-opaque textures to a framebuffer

Tags: opengl-es, rendering, framebuffer, alphablending, render-to-texture

I'm trying to render a set of textured geometry to a single FBO, and then render that FBO to the scene. The problem is that overlapping semi-transparent areas of that geometry are not rendered correctly. They end up too opaque and dark.
If I render the geometry directly to the scene it renders correctly, but I need to render it first to the FBO.

By the way, I'm using the following for blending (according to [opengl - blending with previous contents of framebuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171085/opengl-blending-with-previous-contents-of-framebuffer/4076268)):

- rendering geometry to the FBO: `glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ONE)`
- rendering the FBO to the scene: `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`

I'm doing this for OpenGL ES 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found that the problem was the blending function used to render the geometry to the FBO.

Instead of:

`glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ONE)`

I have to use:

`glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`

And now it works as good as if I was rendering the geometry directly to the scene.